# Writing reusable code

Tags: python

I find myself constantly having to change and adapt old code back and forth repeatedly for different purposes, but occasionally to implement the same purpose it had two versions ago.

One example of this is a function which deals with prime numbers.  Sometimes what I need from it is a list of n primes.  Sometimes what I need is the nth prime.  Maybe I'll come across a third need from the function down the road.

Any way I do it though I have to do the same processes but just return different values.  I thought there must be a better way to do this than just constantly changing the same code.  The possible alternatives I have come up with are:

1. Return a tuple or a list, but this seems kind of messy since there will be all kinds of data types within including lists of thousands of items.
2. Use input statements to direct the code, though I would rather just have it do everything for me when I click run.
3. Figure out how to utilize class features to return class properties and access them where I need them.  This seems to be the cleanest solution to me, but I am not sure since I am still new to this.
4. Just make five versions of every reusable function.

I don't want to be a bad programmer, so which choice is the correct choice?  Or maybe there is something I could do which I have not thought of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Modular, reusable code

Your question is indeed important. It's important in a programmers everyday life. It is the question:

**Is my code reusable?**

If it's not, you will run into code redundancies, having the same lines of code in more than one place. This is the best starting point for bugs. Imagine you want to change the behavior somehow, e.g., because you discovered a potential problem. Then you change it in one place, but you will forget the second location. Especially if your code reaches dimensions like 1,000, 10,0000 or 100,000 lines of code.

It is summarized in the **SRP**, the [*Single-Responsibilty-Principle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). It states that every class (also applicable to functions) should only have one determination, that it "should do just one thing". If a function does more than one thing, you should break it apart into smaller chunks, smaller tasks.

Every time you come across (or write) a function with more than 10 or 20 lines of (real) code, you should be skeptical. Such functions rarely stick to this principle.

For your example, you could identify as individual tasks:

1. generate prime numbers, one by one (generate implies using `yield` for me)
2. collect `n` prime numbers. Uses 1. and puts them into a list
3. get `n`th prime number. Uses 1., but does not save every number, just waits for the `n`th. Does not consume as much memory as 2. does.
4. Find pairs of primes: Uses 1., remembers the previous number and, if the difference to the current number is two, yields this pair
5. collect all pairs of primes: Uses 4. and puts them into a list
6. ...
7. ...

The list is extensible, and you can reuse it at any level. Every function will not have more than 10 lines of code, and you will not be reinventing the wheel everytime.

Put them all into a module, and use it from every script for an Euler Problem related to primes.

In general, I started a small library for my Euler Problem scripts. You really can get used to writing reusable code in "Project Euler".

## Keyword arguments

Another option you didn't mention (as far as I understand) is the use of optional keyword arguments. If you regard small, atomic functions as too complicated (though I really insist you should get used to it) you could add a keyword argument to control the return value. E.g., in some `scipy` functions there is a parameter `full_output`, that takes a bool. If it's False (default), only the most important information is returned (e.g., an optimized value), if it's True some supplementary information is returned as well, e.g., how well the optimization performed and how many iterations it took to converge.

You could define a parameter `output_mode`, with possible values `"list"`, `"last"` ord whatever.

## Recommendation

Stick to small, reusable chunks of code. Getting used to this is one of the most valuable things you can pick up at "Project Euler".

## Remark

If you try to implement the pattern I propose for reusable functions, you might run into a problem immediately at point 1: How to create a generator-style function for this? E.g., if you use the sieve method. But it's not too bad.

Answer (score 0):

My guess, create module that contain:

1. private core function (example: return list of n-th first primes or even something more generall)
2. several wrapper/util functions that use core one and prepare output different ways. (example: n-th prime number)

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce your functions as much as possible, and reuse them.

For example you might have a function `next_prime` which is called repeatedly by `n_primes` and `n_th_prime`.

This also makes your code more maintainable, as if you come up with a more efficient way to count primes, all you do is change the code in `next_prime`.

Furthermore you should make your output as neutral as possible.  If you're function returns several values, it should return a `list` or a generator, *not* a comma separated string.